# Deleting specific Cassandra snapshots

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise

I know that there is a command,

```
nodetool -h localhost -p 7199 clearsnapshot
```

That will delete ALL snapshots, however I only want to delete specific ones - had some trouble getting a node to be able to take snapshots due to misconfigured permissions, while troubleshooting I generated multiple snapshots today that I want to delete while keeping the others.

Can I just go into the individual snapshots directories for each node and manually delete the snapshots I want to get rid of?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can delete individual snapshots manually or use the -t option like this:

"nodetool clearsnapshot -t *snapshot_name*".

The name is the epoch time when the snapshot was taken.

All the clearsnapshot command does is a recursive delete of the specified snapshots in the "snapshots" directories.

See:

[deleting snapshots](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/tools/toolsClearSnapShot.html)

Answer (score 3):

> "Can I just go into the individual snapshots directories for each node and manually delete the snapshots I want to get rid of?"

Yes.

Here is part of a Bash script that I use to automate that:

```
#repository directory
DATADIR="/disk1/cassandra/data"
ARCHIVES="/var/lib/cassandra/archive"

cd $DATADIR

CURRDATE=$(date +%Y%m%d) #= 20140801
SNAPSHOTDATE=$(date --date='6 days ago' '+%Y%m%d')
ARCHIVEDATE=$(date --date='21 days ago' '+%Y%m%d')
DELETEDATE=$(date --date='60 days ago' '+%Y%m%d')
#initialize MAXDATE to 20000101, as EVERYTHING will be greater than that
MAXDATE=20000101

#get all snapshot directories
SNAPSHOTDIRS=$(ls -ld --time-style="+%Y%m%d %H:%M" $PWD/*/*/snapshots | grep drwx | awk '{print $8}')

for SNAPDIR in $SNAPSHOTDIRS
do
        #skip anything from OpsCenter
        if [[ $SNAPDIR == *"OpsCenter"* ]]; then
                echo "Skipping OpsCenter"
        else
                #get time and name of all snapshot files
                FILEDATELIST=$(ls -l --time-style="+%Y%m%d %H:%M" $SNAPDIR | grep drwx | awk '{print $6"="$8}')

                        for SNAPSHOT in $FILEDATELIST
                        do
                                #split with awk
                                FDATE=$(echo $SNAPSHOT | awk -F= '{print $1}')
                                SNAME=$(echo $SNAPSHOT | awk -F= '{print $2}')

                                #move snapshots older than 21 days
                                if [[ $FDATE -lt $ARCHIVEDATE ]]; then
                                        mkdir $ARCHIVES/$SNAME
                                        mv $SNAPDIR/$SNAME/* $ARCHIVES/$SNAME
                                        #echo "mv $SNAPDIR/$SNAME/* $ARCHIVES/$SNAME"
                                fi

                                #check/set MAXDATE
                                #echo "is FDATE($FDATE) -gt MAXDATE($MAXDATE)?"
                                if [[ $FDATE -gt $MAXDATE ]]; then
                                        MAXDATE=$FDATE
                                fi
                        done
        fi
done
```

Answer (score 1):

> Can I just go into the individual snapshots directories for each node
>   and manually delete the snapshots I want to get rid of?

Yes.

Just make sure you don't need them. Snapshots are there for your safety. So you can restore a table if you truncated it accidentally, etc.

Maybe back them up to s3. [OpsCenter](http://www.datastax.com/2015/03/datastax-opscenter-5-1-real-world-test-simulation-of-visual-backup-and-restore-services) does this for you with a point and click interface.